# What are some ways of measuring the divergence between n-lines

Tags: geometry, geometric-measure-theory

I was attempting to discern general patterns in electric data. I subsequenced the data at different tiers. One of which being intraweekly variation. I calculated the euclidean barycenters for each week averaging the week's days as the variables. This led to the creation of four new barycetner averages, BC1,BC2,BC3 and BC4.

I would like to quantify how much these lines diverge from each other in one interpretable metric. Upon research, I found one method is to find their pairwise distances in terms of perpendicular distance, angular distance and parallelism. Then sum them and normalize them between 0 and 1.

I would like to know if there are any field-specific methods I am not cognizant of. Any guidance on the problem of measuring the divergence is welcomed.

[Example containing 4 lines that I which I would like to quantify the difference between](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iRSl.png)